# Maven equivalent of eclipse "clean project"

Tags: linux, eclipse, maven, build

I have a multi-level maven project, which includes a major module which references all the other (also maven) projects:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.evercompliant</groupId>
<artifactId>PipelineMultiModule</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>Pipeline Multi Module</name>
<description>Maven multi module project</description>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>


<properties>

    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<modules>
    <module>../AggregationHandler</module>
    <module>../CrawlerUtils</module>
    <module>../CrawlManager</module>
    <module>../CrawlerDevLibrary</module>
    <module>../DigestManager</module>
    <module>../GCrawler/GoogleCrawler</module>
    <module>../UrlService</module>
    <module>../WebPageCapture</module>
    <module>../WhoisParser</module>
    <module>../TextClassifier</module>
    <module>../scanpipelineservice</module>
</modules>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.34</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

In order to do a full build on windows, I need to execute maven clean and maven install from eclipse.
For some reason, if I don't execute eclipse's "Clean all Projects" between mvn clean and mvn install, the artifact doesn't include the binaries of my project.
For example, the jar created for the AggregationHandler project, will include all of its dependencies (CrawlerUtils, for example), but not the code of AggregationHandler itself.
As I said, it could be fixed by executing "Clean all projects".

Here's the pom.xml file of the AggregationHandler project:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>AggregationHandler</artifactId>

<name>Aggregation Handler</name>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.evercompliant</groupId>
        <artifactId>CrawlerUtils</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-jar</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.evercompliant.aggregationhandler.service.DoAction</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.evercompliant.aggregationhandler.service.DoAction</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.evercompliant</groupId>
    <artifactId>PipelineMultiModule</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../PipelineMultiModule</relativePath>
</parent>
```

Problem is, I now need to build this project on a linux environment, without eclipse. Is there any change that I can do to the pom.xml file(s) in order to fix this problem?

Comment: the equivalent to eclipse clean would be "mvn clean install" on your PipelineMultiMopdule project. Maven will then propagate through all listed modules. You configuration looks ok. So does it work or is there an error?

Comment: Works fine on windows (assuming I do eclipse clean between mvn clean and mvn install). Doesn't work on linux - no error, but project files are not packed

Comment: well whats in the build log then on linux? when maven starts it reads all pom.xml files of your project and prints out a list of the modules it intends to build (at the beginning of the file). Can you post that log output?